# Facebook Like button in Gmaps v3 infoWindow

Tags: facebook, google-maps, facebook-like

I want to show Facebook Like button in Google Maps v3 infoWindow, but I can only show the iframe version. I want more info to share, so I want to implement xfbml version, that doesn't show up in the infoWindow, no Like button can be seen. 
Outside of infoWindow, on php rendered html, (on the same site) xfbml works great, so I guess the problem is between gmaps and facebook script.
Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because the xfbml attempts to render immediately, before the infowindow's DOM is ready.

The fix for it is to wait for the DOM to be ready, then parse the xfbml again. Here's an approximate example (though without your code to go off of, it's probably not exactly correct):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
    FB.XFBML.parse();
});
```

Change the "infoWindow" variable to whatever you named your infowindow object.

Comment: One more question. I wanted to use Fancybox jquery picture popup plugin inside infoWindow, also not worked, should it be the problem with dom ready, too?

Comment: yes it did it. with your help i solved two of my problems. :D mega-thanks!

Comment: fragileninja, any idea how to implement twitter button the same way? Now I see the "Tweet" text if I hover the anchor, but not the Tweet button picture, and clicking this button doesn't pass any data to twitter. This code works of course in normal circumstances: [code] <a href=\"http://twitter.com/share\" class=\"twitter-share-button\" data-url=\"" + url + "\" data-text=\"Új megfigyelés\" data-via=\"madarmegfigyeles.hu\" data-count=\"horizontal\">Tweet</a> [/code]